# Maya UI for browsing assets failing to navigate like OS X finder in Column view?

Tags: python, maya, pyside2, qtwidgets, qfilesystemmodel

I am designing an Asset browser for navigating a pre-defined folder structure and with the help of @musicamante its now looking alot better!

its meant to function in a similar way to OS X's finder in Column view mode:

[image: OS X's finder in Column view mode]

I'm just having a little bit of trouble with how the lists display's.
At launch the lists seem to want to show the root dir in the lists that should be blank.

[image: UI example with problem]

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do have these lists display blank?
Or generally get them to function more like OS X's finder in Column view mode?
At the moment I can only get it to remain expanded as far as 6 but I have no idea what to do if their directory structure goes more than 6 folders deep...
Help?

```py
import os
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel  # Import the Maya MEL module


class AssetBrowser(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, asset_dir, parent=None):
        super(AssetBrowser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.asset_dir = asset_dir
        self.levels = 6  # Number of levels to display
        self.list_titles = ["Type", "Category", "Asset", "LOD", "User", "Scene"]  # List titles
        self.file_views = []  # List to store file views for each level
        self.thumbnail_label = None
        self.file_info_text = None
        self.selected_file_path = None  # Variable to store the selected file path
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Asset Browser')
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Adding the image
        image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r"N:\Asset_Browser\tools\safeBank\icons\safeBank_logoTitle_v001.png")
        image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        layout.addWidget(image_label)

        # Add a frame for the project setting and folder path
        project_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        project_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        project_frame_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(project_frame)
        layout.addWidget(project_frame)

        # Add the set project button
        set_project_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set Project")
        set_project_button.clicked.connect(self.setProject)
        project_frame_layout.addWidget(set_project_button)

        # Add the folder path line edit
        self.folder_path_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        project_frame_layout.addWidget(self.folder_path_lineedit)

        # Add the refresh button
        refresh_icon = QtGui.QPixmap(r"N:\Asset_Browser\tools\safeBank\icons\refresh.png")
        refresh_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        refresh_label.setPixmap(refresh_icon)
        refresh_label.mousePressEvent = self.refreshDirectories
        project_frame_layout.addWidget(refresh_label)

        # Create a layout for the views, thumbnail, and file info
        views_thumbnail_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(views_thumbnail_layout)

        # Create views for each level
        for i in range(self.levels):
            view = QtWidgets.QListView()
            model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
            model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
            view.setModel(model)
            view.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))  # Set icon size
            model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.Files | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
            model.setNameFilters(["*.mb", "*.ma", "*.fbx"])
            model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
            view.clicked.connect(lambda index, i=i: self.viewClicked(index, i))
            views_thumbnail_layout.addWidget(view)
            self.file_views.append(view)
        
        # Populate only the first view upon launch
        self.populateDirectory(self.asset_dir, self.file_views[0])
        
        # Clear the root index for all other views to keep them blank
        for view in self.file_views[1:]:
            view.setRootIndex(QtCore.QModelIndex())
            
        # Connect the directory change for the first view to update subsequent views
        self.file_views[0].doubleClicked.connect(lambda index: self.populateNextView(index))
        
        # Add a frame for the thumbnail and file info
        info_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        info_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        info_frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(info_frame)
        views_thumbnail_layout.addWidget(info_frame)

        # Add thumbnail label
        self.thumbnail_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.thumbnail_label.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        info_frame_layout.addWidget(self.thumbnail_label)

        # Add file info text field
        self.file_info_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        info_frame_layout.addWidget(self.file_info_text)

        # Add feedback field
        self.feedback_field = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.feedback_field)

        # Add a frame for search and notes (occupying half the window width each)
        search_notes_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        search_notes_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        search_notes_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(search_notes_frame)
        layout.addWidget(search_notes_frame)

        # Add a frame for search (occupying half the window width)
        search_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        search_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        search_frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(search_frame)
        search_notes_layout.addWidget(search_frame)

        # Add the search bar to the search frame
        search_bar_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        search_frame_layout.addLayout(search_bar_layout)
        self.search_bar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        search_bar_layout.addWidget(self.search_bar)

        # Add the search button to the search frame
        search_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Search")
        search_button.clicked.connect(self.searchFiles)
        search_bar_layout.addWidget(search_button)
        
        # Connect returnPressed signal of the search bar to searchFiles method
        self.search_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.searchFiles)

        # Add the search results list to the search frame
        self.results_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        search_frame_layout.addWidget(self.results_list)

        # Add a frame for notes (occupying half the window width)
        notes_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        notes_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        notes_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(notes_frame)
        search_notes_layout.addWidget(notes_frame)

        # Add notes box to the notes frame
        notes_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Notes:")
        notes_layout.addWidget(notes_label)
        self.notes_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        notes_layout.addWidget(self.notes_box)

    def populateDirectory(self, directory, view):
        view.model().setRootPath(directory)
        view.setRootIndex(view.model().index(directory))
        
        # Find and select the current directory in the previous file list
        if len(self.file_views) > 1:
            prev_view = self.file_views[self.file_views.index(view) - 1]
            match_indexes = prev_view.model().match(
                prev_view.model().index(prev_view.model().rootPath()),
                QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,
                os.path.basename(directory),
                1,
                QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive
            )
            if match_indexes:
                prev_view.selectionModel().select(
                    match_indexes[0], QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
    
            # Clear the root index for all other views to keep them blank
            for subsequent_view in self.file_views[self.file_views.index(view) + 1:]:
                subsequent_view.setRootIndex(QtCore.QModelIndex())


    def viewClicked(self, index, view_index):
        selected_file_path = self.file_views[view_index].model().filePath(index)
        self.folder_path_lineedit.setText(selected_file_path)  # Update folder path line edit
        if os.path.isdir(selected_file_path):
            self.populateDirectory(selected_file_path, self.file_views[view_index + 1])
        else:
            self.selected_file_path = selected_file_path
            self.displayNotes()
            self.displayThumbnail(selected_file_path)

    def displayNotes(self):
        # Check if a file is selected
        if self.selected_file_path is not None:
            # Construct the note file path by replacing the file extension with '.txt'
            note_file_path = os.path.splitext(self.selected_file_path)[0] + '.txt'
            # Check if the note file exists
            if os.path.isfile(note_file_path):
                # Read and display the contents of the note file
                with open(note_file_path, 'r') as f:
                    notes_content = f.read()
                self.notes_box.setText(notes_content)
                return
        # If no note file found or no file is selected, clear the notes box
        self.notes_box.clear()

    def displayThumbnail(self, file_path):
        # Construct the thumbnail file path
        thumbnail_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '.png'
        # Debug print for the thumbnail path
        print(f"Thumbnail Path: {thumbnail_path}")
        # Check if thumbnail exists
        if os.path.exists(thumbnail_path):
            try:
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(thumbnail_path)
                self.thumbnail_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
                return
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading thumbnail: {e}")
        else:
            print("Thumbnail not found.")

    def refreshDirectories(self, event):
        for view in self.file_views:
            view.model().refresh()

    def setProject(self):
        selected_directory = self.folder_path_lineedit.text()
        mel.eval('setProject "{}";'.format(selected_directory))

    def searchFiles(self):
        search_text = self.search_bar.text()
        selected_directory = self.folder_path_lineedit.text()
        results = []
    
        # Search only within the last selected folder
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(selected_directory):
            for file in files:
                if search_text in file and file.lower().endswith(('.mb', '.ma', '.fbx')):
                    results.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    
        self.results_list.clear()
        self.results_list.addItems(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() or QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    asset_dir = r"N:\Asset_Browser\work\Asset"
    asset_browser = AssetBrowser(asset_dir)
    asset_browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- How it organizes at launch
- I have tried changing how it refreshes
- How it responds to clicks

nothing seems to keep them blank until needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt item views, an invalid QModelIndex represents the *root* of the model. For a QFileSystemModel, that means the file system root (`/` on *nix, "My Computer" on Windows).

There is no immediate way to show an empty list with such a model (maybe there is on Windows using proper `QDir.Filters`, but I'm not sure), but there are possible alternatives:

- create a dummy hidden directory in the program path (ensuring it is empty and has no write access) and set its path for the remaining view;
- create an empty model (such as a QStringListModel) and use it in each remaining view;
- subclass QFileSystemModel, and override `rowCount()` in order to always return 0 whenever required;

In order to achieve the second solution, you obviously need to keep a reference to the model: just create a property when the view is created, and then it's just a matter of resetting the model whenever necessary.

```py
        self.dummy = QStringListModel()
        ...
        for i in range(self.levels):
            view = QtWidgets.QListView()
            view.fsModel = model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
            model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
            ...

    def populateDirectory(self, directory, view):
        view.setModel(view.fsModel)
        ...
        for subsequent_view in self.file_views[self.file_views.index(view) + 1:]:
            subsequent_view.setModel(self.dummy)
```

Alternatively, you can subclass the model and provide a way to "invalidate" it:

```py
class MyFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    _valid = True
    def invalidate(self):
        self.modelAboutToBeReset.emit()
        self._valid = False
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if self._valid:
            return super().rowCount(parent)
        return 0

    def setRootPath(self, path):
        self._valid = True
        return super().setRootPath(path)


class AssetBrowser(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    ...
    def populateDirectory(self, directory, view):
        view.model().setRootPath(directory)
        ...
        for subsequent_view in self.file_views[self.file_views.index(view) + 1:]:
            subsequent_view.invalidate()
```